# How to load a json file depending on a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, constants

I have a trivia game in discord.js and need to be able to fetch questions and answers from a json file from a random number,

This is required because i have multiple lists of questions that it would pick based off like `1.json, 2.json` based of a random number gen but every time i try to fetch a question it says that trivia is not defined even when it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` takes a `string` input, meaning the file path needs to be in quotes.

```
const trivia = require('./game/trivia/1.json');
```

Comment: I am honestly shocked how simple this is while being able to fix my issue